# Laravel: Is it possible to directly test the json response output of a function without actually going through the URI?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests#testing-json-apis), I can test some json returned from my app using the following:

```
$response = $this->json('POST', '/user', ['name' => 'Sally']);

$response
    ->assertStatus(201)
    ->assertJson([
        'created' => true,
    ]);
```

However, is it possible to bypass actually calling up the URI with `$this->json(*method*, *uri*, *data*);` and instead test the direct output of a controller function which returns json? For example, I want to do something like this:

```
// My controller:

function getPageData(){
  $data = array('array', 'of', 'data');
  return response()->json($data);
}

// My Test Class:

$controller = new Primary();
$response = $controller->getPageData();

$response->assertJson([
    'array', 'of', 'data'
]);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What's the use case for this? I'm sure there are better ways to deal with it.

Comment: Ha- I thought I might get asked that ;) I just wanted to test the various methods within my controller directly and systematically. But you're probably right in that I should resign to testing HTTP responses using conventional methods. It just seems it'd be nice to directly test a json string outside of a HTTP response

Comment: Yeah, I do believe there are better ways to go about doing this. I don't currently have a reference, but I read some time ago that the `Request` object should not be initiated outside of an actual request. But, if really needed and you're not referencing the Request object, you could do what I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this for some basic methods, but it might cause side effects:

```
app(SomeController::class)->someControllerMethod();
```

Basically, the `app()` will resolve the dependencies from the constructor, but it won't resolve the method dependencies. So if you typehint something like `method(Request $request)`, it will throw an error.

I'm pretty sure dealing with `request()` will cause unintentional effects since there's no real request going on.

**Edit:**

You could then create a `TestResponse` object, to get all the asserts as well:

```
$res = app(SomeController::class)->someControllerMethod();
$testRes = new Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse($res);
$testRes->assertJson(...); // Will be available
```

Comment: I'm sorry, how would I use this within my test? Setting `$response` to the result of your code and calling `$response->assertJson()` just produces the same result: `BadMethodCallException : Method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::assertJson does not exist.`

Comment: Yeah, you won't have all those asserts available on the response object, which are a part of Laravel's `TestResponse` class. You'd have to do the old way with `$this->assertJson()` (and decode the data and all that).

Comment: I believe that Laravel, behind the scenes, creates a mock `$request` object with the `$this->json(...)` method and returns the `TestReponse`, which implements the testing methods. I don't really see a reason why you'd want to bypass this.

Comment: OK- I'm clearly barking up the wrong tree with this- nevermind. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Actually, the `TestResponse` expects the response object in the constructor. You could just create a new instance and have all those methods available (check my edit in the answer).